# Is my JNA SendInput() call flawed?

Tags: java, jna, sendinput

I've condensed my project code into the example below to show my issue.

The example/snippet references concepts used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35151418/1985071) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18651389/1985071). 
The console output shows 4 events sent; so I expected the output in notepad to be "12", but I only see "1" in Notepad. Can someone point me in the right direction? The jar was built and run on Windows 10 x64.

```
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WTypes.BSTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;

public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int KEYEVENT_SCANCODE = 0x0008;
        int KEYEVENT_UP = 0x0002;

        WinUser.INPUT[] inputArray = (WinUser.INPUT[]) new WinUser.INPUT().toArray(4);

        inputArray[0].type = new WinDef.DWORD(WinUser.INPUT.INPUT_KEYBOARD);
        inputArray[0].input.setType("ki");
        inputArray[0].input.ki.time = new WinDef.DWORD(0);
        inputArray[0].input.ki.wVk  = new WinDef.WORD(0); //using scancodes instead
        inputArray[0].input.ki.dwExtraInfo = new BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR(0);
        inputArray[0].input.ki.dwFlags = new WinDef.DWORD(KEYEVENT_SCANCODE);
        inputArray[0].input.ki.wScan = new WinDef.WORD(0x01);

        inputArray[1].type = new WinDef.DWORD(WinUser.INPUT.INPUT_KEYBOARD);
        inputArray[1].input.setType("ki");
        inputArray[1].input.ki.time = new WinDef.DWORD(0);
        inputArray[1].input.ki.wVk  = new WinDef.WORD(0); //using scancodes instead
        inputArray[1].input.ki.dwExtraInfo = new BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR(0);
        inputArray[1].input.ki.dwFlags = new WinDef.DWORD(KEYEVENT_SCANCODE | KEYEVENT_UP);
        inputArray[1].input.ki.wScan = new WinDef.WORD(0x01);

        inputArray[2].type = new WinDef.DWORD(WinUser.INPUT.INPUT_KEYBOARD);
        inputArray[2].input.setType("ki");
        inputArray[2].input.ki.time = new WinDef.DWORD(0);
        inputArray[2].input.ki.wVk  = new WinDef.WORD(0); //using scancodes instead
        inputArray[2].input.ki.dwExtraInfo = new BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR(0);
        inputArray[2].input.ki.dwFlags = new WinDef.DWORD(KEYEVENT_SCANCODE);
        inputArray[2].input.ki.wScan = new WinDef.WORD(0x02);

        inputArray[3].type = new WinDef.DWORD(WinUser.INPUT.INPUT_KEYBOARD);
        inputArray[3].input.setType("ki");
        inputArray[3].input.ki.time = new WinDef.DWORD(0);
        inputArray[3].input.ki.wVk  = new WinDef.WORD(0); //using scancodes instead
        inputArray[3].input.ki.dwExtraInfo = new BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR(0);
        inputArray[3].input.ki.dwFlags = new WinDef.DWORD(KEYEVENT_SCANCODE | KEYEVENT_UP);
        inputArray[3].input.ki.wScan = new WinDef.WORD(0x02);

        System.out.println("Make sure notepad is in focus...");
        try { Thread.sleep(7000); } catch (Throwable ex) { System.out.println("Interrupted"); } 

        WinDef.DWORD sentInputs = User32.INSTANCE.SendInput( 
            new WinDef.DWORD(inputArray.length),
                inputArray, 
                inputArray[0].size() 
        ); 

        System.out.println("Sent Input Count: " + sentInputs.intValue());
    }
}
```

Console Output:

> E:\SKGDE\my-app\target>java -jar my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>
> Make sure notepad is in focus...
>
> Sent Input Count: 4
>
> E:\SKGDE\my-app\target>

Answer (score 0):

Notepad only shows **"1"** not **"12"** because you are sending wrong scan code. Here you are first sending a scan code for ***ESC KEY*** (*0x01*) and then sending a scan code for ***1 KEY*** (*0x02*).

You should first send scan code for ***1 KEY*** (*0x02*) and then ***2 KEY*** (*0x03*)

Use [ScanCode.java](https://github.com/umer0586/winKeyboad/blob/master/src/winkeyboard/ScanCode.java), so that you dont have to remember scan codes.

```
public interface ScanCode {

public static final int DIK_ESCAPE          =0x01;
public static final int DIK_1               =0x02;
public static final int DIK_2               =0x03;
public static final int DIK_3               =0x04;
public static final int DIK_4               =0x05;
public static final int DIK_5               =0x06;
public static final int DIK_6               =0x07;
public static final int DIK_7               =0x08;
public static final int DIK_8               =0x09;
public static final int DIK_9               =0x0A;
public static final int DIK_0               =0x0B;
public static final int DIK_MINUS           =0x0C;   /* - on main keyboard */
public static final int DIK_EQUALS          =0x0D;
public static final int DIK_BACK            =0x0E;    /* backspace */
public static final int DIK_TAB             =0x0F;
public static final int DIK_Q               =0x10;
public static final int DIK_W               =0x11;
public static final int DIK_E               =0x12;
public static final int DIK_R               =0x13;
public static final int DIK_T               =0x14;
public static final int DIK_Y               =0x15;
public static final int DIK_U               =0x16;
public static final int DIK_I               =0x17;
public static final int DIK_O               =0x18;
public static final int DIK_P               =0x19;
public static final int DIK_LBRACKET        =0x1A;
public static final int DIK_RBRACKET        =0x1B;
public static final int DIK_RETURN          =0x1C;   /* Enter on main keyboard */
public static final int DIK_LCONTROL        =0x1D;
public static final int DIK_A               =0x1E;
public static final int DIK_S               =0x1F;
public static final int DIK_D               =0x20;
public static final int DIK_F               =0x21;
public static final int DIK_G               =0x22;
public static final int DIK_H               =0x23;
public static final int DIK_J               =0x24;
public static final int DIK_K               =0x25;
public static final int DIK_L               =0x26;
public static final int DIK_SEMICOLON       =0x27;
public static final int DIK_APOSTROPHE      =0x28;
public static final int DIK_GRAVE           =0x29;   /* accent grave */
public static final int DIK_LSHIFT          =0x2A;
public static final int DIK_BACKSLASH       =0x2B;
public static final int DIK_Z               =0x2C;
public static final int DIK_X               =0x2D;
public static final int DIK_C               =0x2E;
public static final int DIK_V               =0x2F;
public static final int DIK_B               =0x30;
public static final int DIK_N               =0x31;
public static final int DIK_M               =0x32;
public static final int DIK_COMMA           =0x33;
public static final int DIK_PERIOD          =0x34;   /* . on main keyboard */
public static final int DIK_SLASH           =0x35;    /* / on main keyboard */
public static final int DIK_RSHIFT          =0x36;
public static final int DIK_MULTIPLY        =0x37;    /* * on numeric keypad */
public static final int DIK_LMENU           =0x38;    /* left Alt */
public static final int DIK_SPACE           =0x39;
public static final int DIK_CAPITAL         =0x3A;
public static final int DIK_F1              =0x3B;
public static final int DIK_F2              =0x3C;
public static final int DIK_F3              =0x3D;
public static final int DIK_F4              =0x3E;
public static final int DIK_F5              =0x3F;
public static final int DIK_F6              =0x40;
public static final int DIK_F7              =0x41;
public static final int DIK_F8              =0x42;
public static final int DIK_F9              =0x43;
public static final int DIK_F10             =0x44;
public static final int DIK_NUMLOCK         =0x45;
public static final int DIK_SCROLL          =0x46;    /* Scroll Lock */
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD7         =0x47;
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD8         =0x48;
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD9         =0x49;
public static final int DIK_SUBTRACT        =0x4A;    /* - on numeric keypad */
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD4         =0x4B;
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD5         =0x4C;
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD6         =0x4D;
public static final int DIK_ADD             =0x4E;    /* + on numeric keypad */
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD1         =0x4F;
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD2         =0x50;
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD3         =0x51;
public static final int DIK_NUMPAD0         =0x52;
public static final int DIK_DECIMAL         =0x53;   /* . on numeric keypad */
public static final int DIK_OEM_102         =0x56;    /* <> or \| on RT 102-key keyboard (Non-U.S.) */
public static final int DIK_F11             =0x57;
public static final int DIK_F12             =0x58;
public static final int DIK_F13             =0x64;   /*                     (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_F14             =0x65;    /*                     (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_F15             =0x66;    /*                     (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_KANA            =0x70;    /* (Japanese keyboard)            */
public static final int DIK_ABNT_C1         =0x73;    /* /? on Brazilian keyboard */
public static final int DIK_CONVERT         =0x79;    /* (Japanese keyboard)            */
public static final int DIK_NOCONVERT       =0x7B;    /* (Japanese keyboard)            */
public static final int DIK_YEN             =0x7D;    /* (Japanese keyboard)            */
public static final int DIK_ABNT_C2         =0x7E;    /* Numpad . on Brazilian keyboard */
public static final int DIK_NUMPADEQUALS    =0x8D;    /* = on numeric keypad (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_PREVTRACK       =0x90;    /* Previous Track (DIK_CIRCUMFLEX on Japanese keyboard) */
public static final int DIK_AT              =0x91;    /*                     (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_COLON           =0x92;    /*                     (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_UNDERLINE       =0x93;    /*                     (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_KANJI           =0x94;    /* (Japanese keyboard)            */
public static final int DIK_STOP            =0x95;    /*                     (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_AX              =0x96;    /*                     (Japan AX) */
public static final int DIK_UNLABELED       =0x97;    /*                        (J3100) */
public static final int DIK_NEXTTRACK       =0x99;    /* Next Track */
public static final int DIK_NUMPADENTER     =0x9C;   /* Enter on numeric keypad */
public static final int DIK_RCONTROL        =0x9D;
public static final int DIK_MUTE            =0xA0;   /* Mute */
public static final int DIK_CALCULATOR      =0xA1;    /* Calculator */
public static final int DIK_PLAYPAUSE       =0xA2;    /* Play / Pause */
public static final int DIK_MEDIASTOP       =0xA4;    /* Media Stop */
public static final int DIK_VOLUMEDOWN      =0xAE;    /* Volume - */
public static final int DIK_VOLUMEUP        =0xB0;    /* Volume + */
public static final int DIK_WEBHOME         =0xB2;    /* Web home */
public static final int DIK_NUMPADCOMMA     =0xB3;   /* , on numeric keypad (NEC PC98) */
public static final int DIK_DIVIDE          =0xB5;    /* / on numeric keypad */
public static final int DIK_SYSRQ           =0xB7;
public static final int DIK_RMENU           =0xB8;    /* right Alt */
public static final int DIK_PAUSE           =0xC5;    /* Pause */
public static final int DIK_HOME            =0xC7;    /* Home on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_UP              =0xC8;    /* UpArrow on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_PRIOR           =0xC9;    /* PgUp on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_LEFT            =0xCB;    /* LeftArrow on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_RIGHT           =0xCD;    /* RightArrow on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_END             =0xCF;    /* End on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_DOWN            =0xD0;    /* DownArrow on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_NEXT            =0xD1;    /* PgDn on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_INSERT          =0xD2;    /* Insert on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_DELETE          =0xD3;    /* Delete on arrow keypad */
public static final int DIK_LWIN            =0xDB;    /* Left Windows key */
public static final int DIK_RWIN            =0xDC;    /* Right Windows key */
public static final int DIK_APPS            =0xDD;    /* AppMenu key */
public static final int DIK_POWER           =0xDE;    /* System Power */
public static final int DIK_SLEEP           =0xDF;    /* System Sleep */
public static final int DIK_WAKE            =0xE3;    /* System Wake */
public static final int DIK_WEBSEARCH       =0xE5;    /* Web Search */
public static final int DIK_WEBFAVORITES    =0xE6;    /* Web Favorites */
public static final int DIK_WEBREFRESH      =0xE7;    /* Web Refresh */
public static final int DIK_WEBSTOP         =0xE8;    /* Web Stop */
public static final int DIK_WEBFORWARD      =0xE9;    /* Web Forward */
public static final int DIK_WEBBACK         =0xEA;    /* Web Back */
public static final int DIK_MYCOMPUTER      =0xEB;    /* My Computer */
public static final int DIK_MAIL            =0xEC;    /* Mail */
public static final int DIK_MEDIASELECT     =0xED;    /* Media Select */


}
```